# Looking for the following story that sounds like something Cory Doctorow might have written

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story is set in a US alternate history where wi-fi and 3G access are heavily controlled and people caught stealing Internet access from Canada (via satellite) are jailed.

The protagonist is one such former broadband poacher, who is jailed. Eventually his reputation is restored by a cute French girl who spirits him to Paris. Nokia still rules.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The story is "**Unwirer**" by Charles Stross (written in collaboration with Cory Doctorow).
It was originally released in his 2009 collection of short fiction; "[Wireless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless%3a_The_Essential_Charles_Stross)"

You can read an online (and copyright safe) version [here](http://craphound.com/unwirer/) which also shows the various edits and differing versions as written by each of the co-authors.

> "The unwirers are heroes in Europe. You hear them talk, it's like
>   listening to a course in US constitutional freedoms. But here, you
>   people are crooks, cable-thieves, pirates, abetters of terrorists. I
>   want to change that!"